# CakePhp 3.0 - Missing Helper

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I need to use the `UploadPack` plugin in my CakePhp project, but my cake doesn't find the plugin's Helper. I actually tried to create some custom helpers for myself as well, but none has worked. I have the helper files saved in `app/src/View/Helper/` (my custom helper) and `app/plugins/UploadPack/src/View/Helper/` (the plugin's helper, I didn't create nor modify this), I have referenced the helpers in `$helpers[]` in the right controllers, and I don't know what else is left to be done. I don't know if code is relevant, but I'll post them below anyway. Please help.

app/src/Controller/UsersController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;

class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $uses = array('User');
    var $helpers = ['Html', 'Form', 'UploadPack.Upload'];

    public function add() {
        // Do not let logged in users register a new account
        if(!isset($this->request->session()->read('Auth')['User']) ||
           $this->request->session()->read('Auth')['User']['role']==='admin'){
            $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data);
            $user->properties = 'user';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                    $this->Flash->success('The user has been saved.');
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
                }
            }
            $this->set(compact('user'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('You are already logged in.');
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'index']);
        }
    }

    // Irrelevant code below
}
```

Some file architecture (including some probably irrelevant directories)

```
app/
    bin/
    config/
    plugins/
        UploadPack/
            src/
                Model/
                View/
                    Helper/
                        UploaderHelper.php
    src/
        Controller/
            UsersController.php
        Templates/
            Comments/
            Users/
                add.ctp
                edit.ctp
                index.ctp
                view.ctp
```

Output when accessing any file in `localhost:8765/users/`

```
Error: UploadPack.UploadHelper could not be found. Make sure your plugin was
loaded from config/bootstrap.php and Composer is able to autoload its classes,
see Loading a plugin and Plugins - autoloading plugin classes

Error: Create the class UploadHelper below in file:
/home/eburn/comments/plugins/UploadPack/src/View/Helper/UploadHelper.php
```

Comment: How did you install the plugin? Why is the folder name in your structure dump `plugin` (singular) and not `plugins` (plural)? Have you read the Cookbook sections that error message told you to check out?

Comment: @ndm I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack), the "plugin" in singular was my mistake when writing the question, and the error message doesn't tell me to read the Cookbook, but I have read the [sections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html)

Comment: The error message has two links to appropriate sections in the cookbook, check them out. Anyways, quote from the instructions that you've linked: "*UploadPack was developed with CakePHP 1.2 RC3...*" - it's not compatible with CakePHP 3!

Comment: @ndm Oh I'm sorry, it does have the links. But I had read them before. About it not being compatible with CakePHP 3.0, I was afraid of that, but I wasn't sure. Thanks for your help!